# Intellij Structural Search: How to find empty try catch blocks?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, structural-search

How can i find the empty try catch blocks?

Using the Copy existing template... I found the structural search for try catch:

```
try {
  $TryStatement$;
} catch($ExceptionType$ $Exception$) {
  $CatchStatement$;
}
```

I want to enhance it so that it does only find try catches with empty catch blocks

It should find:

```
 try {
        assertTrue(output.validate());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO something
    }
```

or

```
    try {
        assertTrue(output.validate());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

or

```
try {
        assertTrue(output.validate());
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

However not:

```
 try {
        assertTrue(output.validate());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Right now it obviously finds both since there's no differentiation betweens. 
How can I add this extra check?

Comment: Instead of using structural search, you could also do: Analyze / Run Inspection by Name / Empty 'catch' Block

Comment: thx, but it does not find the empty catch with commentar, like in first example.

Comment: The *Empty 'catch' block* inspection has an option to count comments as content which you can disable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the template you have found and on CatchStatement variable set Min count and Max count to 0.